# How can I get the natural width and height of an svg image element?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to do something relatively simple. I'm trying to get the following working in D3:

- Draw an image as an SVG element in its natural width and height.
- Be able to click on this image to draw circles with D3.

I'm stuck on how to draw the image as an SVG element. So far I have:

```
content.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href",this.store.image_url);
```

But how can I get the natural width / height of this element?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with a bit of javascript

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){

        img.naturalWidth and img.naturalHeight can be read off within here

};
img.src = this.store.image_url;
```

Comment: Oh neat. Now how can I use this Image data in my svg element without loading the image twice?

Comment: Browsers will most likely cache it if they can. If not, ask a new question with details of what you've tried.

Comment: Kinda the same question. Your solution creates a DOM Image element and reads the width and height off of that - but how can I integrate this naturally with svg?

Comment: Via setAttribute? You really need another question as what you're asking now is really unclear.