# How to get the natural dimension of an svg <image> element?

Tags: javascript, image, svg

In HTML we have the `<img>` element which kinda maps to the `Image` object. Both have two properties called `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`. When you want to set the dimension of an image to its natural dimension in the `load` callback you can do that easily with

```
var img = new Image
img.addEventListener('load' function(e) {
    // do whatever with naturalWidt/Height
})
```

However when you want to set the dimension of an svg `<image>` element you cant rely on this because this element has no `natural` properies:

```
var img = document.createElementNS(namespace, 'image')
img.addEventListener('load' function(e) {
    img.setAttributeNS(namespace, 'width', img.naturalWidth) // dont work
})
```

So my question is: **How can you set the dimension of an svg `<image>` elemet without loading the image with `new Image` before?
And is there anything planed in the specs to support such `natural` properties?**

Comment: I find myself wondering the same thing. Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: What iam doing is basically loading an Image objective and when it loaded i change my svg image to the desired width and height. Maybe i should ask the mailing list

Answer (score 1):

Svg `<image>` elements missing `width` or `height` attributes will **by default use the natural pixel dimensions.**

However, the **parent svg element won't grow automatically** by means of adjusting it's `viewBox` or actual layout `with`and `height`.

#### getBBox()

Use svg [`getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method to retrieve the bounding box of any ["renderable element"](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/render.html#Definitions).

Similar to HTML `<img>` elements we need to wait **until the image src is loaded.**

`getBBox()` requires an element to be **appended to the DOM** - otherwise it returns a 0x0 bounding box.

#### Example: append svg `<image>`, load src and adjust svg size

```js
let svg = document.getElementById("svg");

function loadImg(href) {
  // create namespaced svg element
  let ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  let image = document.createElementNS(ns, "image");
  // set href
  image.setAttribute("href", href);
  svg.appendChild(image);

  image.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
    // get bounding box
    let bb = e.currentTarget.getBBox();
    let [width, height] = [bb.width, bb.height];
    image.setAttribute("width", width);
    image.setAttribute("height", height);
    //adjust viewBox
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height].join(" "));
    // optional - if you resize your svg via css
    svg.setAttribute("width", width);
    svg.setAttribute("height", height);
  });
}
```

```css
svg{
  overflow:visible;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<p><button type="button" onclick="loadImg('https://placehold.co/600x400')">load image</button></p>
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
</svg> adjacent text.
```

Since browsers usually cache image requests you could also use the aforementioned `new image()` approach to fetch the `naturalWidth` and apply it to the svg `<image>` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007543/how-can-i-get-the-natural-width-and-height-of-an-svg-image-element)